# displayTag to use contents from 2 arrayLists

Tags: displaytag

I am working with displayTag to display the monthly summary of contents in UI (first 7 columns) and export all the day-wise records to excel (7+3 more day-wise data columns).

I now have 2 arraylists returned to JSP one with only summary records and another with summary + detail records. We need summary in UI and summary+detail in excel.

Is there a way we can refer 2 arraylists in displayTag one for the UI and another excel data ?

Comment: just to add here is the detail- arraylist data. first 7 columns available in Summary arraylist as well. of Teacher Name   Student Name   RollNo    Grade  from   to  Total-No-of-days-delayed  Late-date   Late-Time  Late By
Teacher Name   Student Name   RollNo    Grade  from   to  Total-No-of-days-delayed  Late-date   Late-Time  Late By
Teacher Name   Student Name   RollNo    Grade  from   to  Total-No-of-days-delayed  Late-date   Late-Time  Late By

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. used the detail arrayList and 'Group" property to list summary records, where as excel take all records as expected. Also used 'media=html" to specify which records to display only on webpage. this resolved the issue.